# Split_array_add_first_part_to_the_end

Tags: java, arrays

```
There is a given array and split it from a specified position, and move the first part of the array add to the end. 
 Input : arr[] = {12, 10, 5, 6, 52, 36}
            k = 2
Output : arr[] = {5, 6, 52, 36, 12, 10}
```

```
public class Split_array_add_first_part_to_the_end {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        int a[]= {12,10,5,6,52,36};
int i,j;
int n=a.length;
int x=a[0];

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    int temp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[i+1];
    temp=a[i];
    
}
a[n-1]=x;
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
    
    }
}
```

a[n-1]=x; ->this replace the 12
how to rotate the 10th value

> I am getting output like this
> 10
> 5
> 6
> 52
> 36
> 12

> Please explain the flow of execution and what mistake I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int a[] = {12, 10, 5, 6, 52, 36};

    // use int declaration in for-loop.
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            int temp = a[i]; // swap number to end per iteration
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
```

You almost had it. This solution is working
I have seen that you declared the index as variable outside the for-loop (not necessary). I would recommend you to start smaller and break problems down each.

Main thing I guess you wanted to do is cycle through the array per k times iterations. I would starting on progamming:

1. Printing each item;
2. Swapping one item;
3. Swapping items each index (means swapped to end)
4. Just do it k-times by surround the loop with another one (k-loop)

My approach would be using Collections and rotate to shorten it more

```
    Integer a[] = {12, 10, 5, 6, 52, 36};
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a);
    Collections.rotate(list, -2); // Rotate the list backwards by two elements
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to fix it and clearly understood.